# How deep do i have to put my raspberry pi pico pins in a breadboard

Tags: pi-pico, wiring, breadboard

I'm trying to make breadboard circuit with my Raspberry Pi Pico and I'm not sure if I have to push it entirely in the holes or it's good at half?

Here's the model: [Freenove Raspberry Pi Pico (Compatible with Arduino IDE) Pre-Soldered Header, Development Board, Python C Java Code, Detailed Tutorial, Example Projects](https://www.amazon.ca/Freenove-Raspberry-Compatible-Pre-Soldered-Development/dp/B09X33TBY3)

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking.  Have you soldered extra long pins to the Pico?

Comment: no i didn't soldered anything i bought with it already on heres the model: https://www.amazon.ca/Freenove-Raspberry-Compatible-Pre-Soldered-Development/dp/B09X33TBY3/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=3B0SP3W7IZWL4&keywords=raspberry%2Bpi%2Bpico&qid=1674057185&sprefix=raspberry%2Bpi%2Bpico%2Caps%2C292&sr=8-2-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzUU8xVURMQzM4TFAzJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNDEyMzMwUENIQlZKVkZGM09FJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA5MjMxOTZJQzNTN0xDRVRGUVcmd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl&th=1

Comment: Push it down as far as it will go.  The pico should be almost flush to the breadboard.

Comment: i figured it out my self it's just a part of my breadboard or something that wasn't working but i got it it's working and all good now thanks for trying to help

Comment: Nvm i just had to push a bit more than it worked

Answer (score 5):

Push it down as far as it will go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have have the chance please look "inside" a breadboard, every row has 5 metal "clips" that will "hug" pins when they come in. Such clips are positioned on top of the assembly, close to the entrance hole.

That said, you could insert pins as shallow as say 2mm, already making some electrical contact; but that doesn't mean good/safe contact. As other have pointed you will be safe pressing and inserting pins as deep as they go.